# выбор пункта из выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript

Есть [сайт](http://respect-krd.ru/) если нажать на  кнопку Заказать стол, появляется форма ввода. так вот я выбираю из выпадающего списка пункт, но в форме отпраки появляется совершенно не тот пункт который выбирал,если нажать еще раз на выбранный пункт,то он меняется на тот который нужен. 
вот как у меня он реализован

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.formmenu_1').click(function(){
    $('#bil').val($(this).html());
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="1_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_a  non_1">Русский бильярд</div>
<div  id="2_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1">Американский пул</div>
<div  id="3_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1">Снукер</div>
<input type="text" id="bil" name="bil"/>
```

Comment: в сниппете что вы привели имеется та проблема, что вы описываете? Если да, то скажите что именно не так как вы хотите (ибо работает вроде как положено), если нет, то предоставьте код который не работает.

Comment: Пока что, единственное что могу предположиться: сниппет вы привели просто для примера, а на селект вы так же вешаете `click`, в итоге вы получаете в инпут текущее значение селекта, а не то на которое меняете, в таком случае надо заменить `click` на `change`, наверное нужно больше подробностей.

Comment: да,работает,но если зайдете на сайт http://respect-krd.ru/ и кликните на Заказать стол затем выберете стол ,то увидите проблему. при выборе из выпадающего списка в поле не появляется выбранный пункт

Comment: поставил change, вообще перестал выводить выбранный пункт

Comment: для примера не ставил,ставил так как есть на сайте. но я понял что нужно change ставить,только вот нужно что то дописать ибо не хочет работать если вместо click поставить change)

Comment: Не, ченж тут не поможет, я думал у вас на рабочем сайте там реально селект, тогда бы помог ченж, но вам все же надо использовать клик, только пока не пойму что там происходит и как-то переписать.

Comment: В общем у вас там в function.js есть скрипт, который срабатывает после, он не дает себя перебить, править надо его, а не сверху городить, других вариантов я не вижу